# How i increase my code performance when using core service?

Tags: publishing, core-service, schema

I am creating a publication,schema,component, folder,structure group,pages,template,tenplate building block using core services.

there is a lot of component it may be 200 or more and many folder and structure group 
are there when thease are creating from core service it tacking 1 hour or more then one hour how I decrease this time .

please give me any suggestion it is a very big issue for me.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have lot of classes how I  decrease the core service sending and receiving time

Comment: You're going to have to share details of how you're accessing the core service (including code) if you want answers to this question.

Comment: I guess you should start by doing a code review and applying some generic good principles like cache, reduce number of calls for data you already have, and add some measurements to your code. It's basic code optimization, nothing specific to Tridion or core service really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where it is slow.

For example, if you are using a soap-based transport over a poor network, you may see poorer performance than running your scripts on the server using net-tcp.

If your code needlessly creates objects many times inside a loop, consider moving such object creations outside the loop (where possible) so that they happen less often.

If your Tridion server is running on poor hardware or using a slow database connection, you may be able to make some improvements there.

All in all - the general principle is not to try to guess. Most guesses in performance work are wrong. (Although - obviously you can sometimes find obviously poor code and fix it.) So measure where the problems are, and then fix them. This might mean using profiling tools like those in Visual Studio, or you may have to add some logging code. To check the performance of your server, you can first look in the logs for obvious problems, but then go further and use system tools like task manager, resource manager and perfmon to look for things like memory problems, issues with disk IO, etc.

Also bear in mind that you might not find any such problems. Maybe you are simply asking a lot of your server, and the times you are getting are reasonable. In that case, you may wish to look at your overall architecture from a performance viewpoint - Tridion scales out very nicely, so moving to a bigger architecture will often be feasible.